# SQLAlchemy - using hybrid properties in a query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use a SQLAlchemy hybrid property like this

```
class Metric(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'metric'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Float, nullable=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def dominance(self):
        return 1 - abs(0.5 - float(self.value))
```

Now, I use this in my model like this

```
class MetricModel(BaseModel):
    def get_dominance(self):
        self.query(Metric).filter(Metric.dominance >  0.5).order_by(Metric.dominance.desc()).limit(2).all()
```

This is a flask app and it's being called like this

```
model = MetricModel(db)
with db.session():
    print(model.get_dominant_traits())
```

This gives me an error

`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'InstrumentedAttribute'`

From the error it looks like there is no result set, hence the failure. I followed the docs here http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html
What should I do differently?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to create [expression](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior)

```
from sqlalchemy import func

class Metric(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'metric'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Float, nullable=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def dominance(self):
        return 1 - abs(0.5 - self.value)

    @dominance.expression
    def dominance(cls):
        return 1 - func.abs(0.5 - cls.value)
```

Comment: This link provides a pretty good explanation https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html

Comment: But what if the data is on the instance level and different for every object (using another hybrid property in the expression)?